# Monodroid generics not covariant?

Tags: generics, mono, xamarin.android, covariance

**EDIT:**
*It seems to be confirmed that covariant generics are not yet supported.  To make sure it makes it in the next release please email Xamarin and request this feature.*

The following code gives me an error (at the linq statement).  Identical code works fine in Microsoft clr c# 4.0.

**Error:**

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<LinqTest.Person>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<LinqTest.Entity>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

**Code:**

```
[Activity(Label = "LinqTest", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class Activity1 : Activity {

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        var names = new List<string> {
                                         "Joe",
                                         "Bob",
                                         "Jim",
                                         "Jane"
                                     };

        IEnumerable<Entity> query =
            from e in names
            select new Person() {Name = e};

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        var button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);

        button.Click += delegate {
                            button.Text = string.Format("{0}", query.Count());
                        };
    }
}

public class Entity {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Person : Entity {
    public string Workplace { get; set; }
}

public class Animal : Entity {
    public string FurColour { get; set; }
}
```

Am I correct or am I missing something?  If so recommendations on refactoring this?

**Also, if so, consider this an official feature request for monodroid - support for covariant generic support. :)**

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither MonoTouch nor Mono for Android has support for covariance right now. It will be supported in a future release (probably some time in the second half of this year).

Comment: Thanks - I look forward to this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you forget to set the framework version to 4.0? Works for me with Mono 2.10.8. Although it may also be some android specific limitation (partial generic support listed 
[here](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/about/limitations), however not explicitly stated).

Comment: I am using the latest version of monodroid.  I am targeting android 2.2 but do not know where to set the target version of clr/c# for an monodroid android application project - where is that?  I am using Visual studio 2010.  Did the above (covariant generics) work for you in a monodroid project?  Can you post the code?  Thanks.

Comment: Can't check whether it works for monodroid - I don't have it. I've just used your code in usual Mono project on Linux to check whether covariants work there. And they do. Also the error message is as if you have used classes from pre-4.0 framework. It may be, however, that IEnumerable<T> implementation for Monodroid is not covariant too. Normally you could set framework version in project properties, on the appliaction tab. I do not know if it can be done the same way in Monodroid project.

Comment: I also suspect that the monodroid implementation is non-covariant.  I search through all properties and settings everywhere and could not find a way to specify target c#/clr version in a monodroid project. Thanks.

Comment: I'd ask Xamarin directly. If it is not supported yet, I think it should be soon ("This will be improved in a future release").

Answer (score 0):

Not having covariant support for generics was resulting in ugly code so I went back to this problem and came up with a simple hack to allow a simulated covariant effect.

I would like any feedback on making this even simpler.  Also I am concerned about performance - any thoughts.  Its still not perfect but allows me to clean up other code.

Here is the new code sample that simulates covariant generics on monodroid.

```
    [Activity(Label = "CovariantTest", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class Activity1 : Activity {
    int count = 1;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);

        var names = new List<string> {
                                         "Joe",
                                         "Bob",
                                         "Jim",
                                         "Jane"
                                     };

        IEnumerable<Entity>query =
            (from e in names
            select (new Person() { Name = e }) as Entity).ToList();

        Person p =  query[2] as Person;

        button.Click += delegate { button.Text = string.Format("{0}", p.Test()); };
    }
}

public class Entity {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Person : Entity {
    public string Workplace { get; set; }
    public string Test() {
        return "I am a person";
    }
}

public class Animal : Entity {
    public string FurColour { get; set; }
}
```